# keyboard input issue with special foreign characters

Tags: .net, vb6, winforms-interop

I have a VB6 application, calling a VB.Net Winform with Form Interop.
The .Net Winform is a user control that is embedded in a VB6 MDI-child Form.

All works fine, except that it's not possible to input special foreign characters in some TextBox of the .Net user control. For example, I cannot input special polish characters like ą ó ż, ... 
Instead of the character that I type, the control display another one (¹ instead of ą, for example).

The special characters can be displayed in the Textbox, if the text is filled by the program, or when I make a copy/paste.

I can input these characters in any full VB6 form, or when the .Net user control is called from a Winform .Net application.

In the .net user control, I've forced the InputLanguage with the foreign language, but it's the same issue.